# Insert value into Mutable List using for loop (index wise) in scala

Tags: list, scala, indexing, insert, mutable

i want to insert values in mutable list index wise using for loop as following

```
var firstList=List("A","B","C","D")
var newList = new ListBuffer[String]()  
for(i<-0 to firstList.length-1){
    **newList(i)**=firstList(i)
}
```

i want to do similar task.. I know how to insert values using " newList+=firstList(i) " this method, but i want this with index wise approach

Comment: "index wise" what does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

Use def insert(n: Int, elems: A*) method in scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/ArrayBuffer.html